# How to print For Loop Change HTML Label

Tags: jquery, loops, label

I'm trying to print the For loop of a range:

```
0 > 1000
```

The question is:  is possible to change  the HTML Label with a "CHRNOMETER" EFFECT?

I've been trying with this:

```
    <span id="timer"></span> 

<script>
var startTime = 350;

function change(i) {

     document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = i;

    }


for(i = 0; i < startTime; i++){

setInterval(change(i), 10000);
}
</script>
```

But the code only sho me the final result.

I need to set the interval.  It the final effect should be something like a millisecond Chronometer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope understand what you are saying, an option to make a chronometer effect is:

```js
var finish = 300;
var count = 0;

spanTimer = document.getElementById("timer")

function change(count) {
  spanTimer.innerHTML = count;
  if (count >= finish)
   clearInterval(eventInterval);
  count++
  return count
}

eventInterval = setInterval(function() {
 count = change(count);
}, 10);
```

```html
<span id="timer"></span>
```

Notes:

1. Call `document.getElementById("timer")` only once, despite its performance is very fast, try to apply good practice.
2. Make your logic taking in account that `setInterval` has a minimum time of 10 ms, if you write less than 10 ms it'll take 10 ms as default.
3. Is necessary stop `setInterval` with `clearInterval` when you arrive to your target.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is unnecessary since set interval repeats itself by default. the first argument should be a function so that it works correctly (you passed a function call)

```js
var i =0;
var startTime = 100;

function change() {
if(i<startTime)
  i++;
else
   clearInterval(loop);
console.log('setInterval is looping');
     document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = i;
    }

   var loop= setInterval(function(){change()}, 100);
```

```html
<span id="timer"></span>
```